# Mac slow down after xcode update

Tags: macos, mac, xcode, memory

My mac is going very slow after I update xcode to 8.2 I checked activity monitor which is showing a process name ibtoold many times with huge memory consumption.[image] Can anyone help please?

Comment: What version of macOS X are you running? A poster in [this thread at Apple Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66551) says that upgrading to Sierra fixed the problem. And this: _"In my case, I noticed that if you set the root view's Top Bar value (Attributes Inspector > Simulated Metrics > Top Bar) from `Inferred` to `Opaque Navigation Bar`, it turns into hogging mode. Everytime you switch to this Nib file, your CPU usage turns up. Switching the value back to its default seems to resolve it."_

Comment: OS is EL Capton 10.11.6

Comment: I quit the xcode but the logs are still there in activity monitor

Comment: Kill the `ibtoold` and `xcode` processes, then report back what happened.

Answer (score 2):

Did they finally disappear?  I suspect it was updating/recompiling your Xcode interface files and once done, these processes should go away.

Comment: Nope. They are still there.

Comment: Kill them and see what happens

Comment: killed all the processes but xcode is still slow responsive. May be it's an issue with xcode 8.2